# Is there any possible way to make hook flash to any extension throoght software?

Tags: hook, asterisk, asteriskami

I like to make conference call following this step.

1. 2222 make call to 3333 (phone)
2. 3333 receive phone call (phone)
3. simulate push flash button to 2222 thought AMI/? (software)
4. originate call to 4444 throught AMI (software)
5. 4444 receive phone call (phone)
6. simulate push flash button to 2222 thought AMI/? again (software)
7. 222 333 4444 speaking to each other in the same channel (phone)

I know that AMI doesn't have exactly function to make hook flash. (some trick?)

Is there any suggestion to complete step 3 and 6 through software it may be AMI or anything else.

Resource:

```
AMI = Asterisk Manager Interface
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_flash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect two parties by originating a call with the originate command, using the "application" parameter. From the console it's like this:

originate SIP/2222 application Dial SIP/3333

That will originate a call to extension 2222 and when it's answered, a call to extension 3333 will be placed.

To place the third call, you can have something like this in your dialplan:

[thirdcall]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/4444)
exten => s,2,NoOp

And change the originate command to something like this:

originate SIP/2222 application Dial SIP/3333,G(thirdcall^s^1)

This will place a call to ext. 2222, and when the call is answered, a call is placed to ext. 3333. Then when the call to 3333 is answered, it will send ext. 3333 to to thirdcall,s,1 on the dialplan, which is a dial command to extension 4444 (and it also sends extension 4444 to s,2 which is a NoOp, upon answer).

Try it and let us know if the three calls are bridged and all parties can talk among themselves.

Personally I think it would be easier to call all three parties and send them to a conference room...